# How do I return a flag on integer overflow in Rust?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow

Swift has integer overflow arithmetic functions which return a flag whether the number has overflowed or not. Do we have same thing in Rust?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you note, there are [intrinsics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.add_with_overflow.html) for this but these are `unsafe` and somewhat annoying to use.

Before Rust 1.0, the standard library provided wrappers that detect the overflow for the 4 arithmetic operations in the form of [`CheckedAdd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.CheckedAdd.html), [`CheckedSub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.CheckedSub.html), [`CheckedMul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.CheckedMul.html) and [`CheckedDiv`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.CheckedDiv.html).

As of Rust 1.0, these traits no longer exist and there are just inherent methods on each numeric type, such as [`i32::checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_add).

However, these just *detect* overflow and do not return the overflowed-result:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", 5u16.checked_add(65530u16));
    println!("{:?}", 6u16.checked_add(65530u16));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6e6c6b27a1584f211e6624762956afdf&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Prints:

```
Some(65535)
None
```

Answer (score 17):

Since Rust 1.7.0, there's `overflowing_<operation>(rhs)` defined on integer types.

Example for [`overflowing_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.overflowing_add):

> Calculates `self` + `rhs`
>
> Returns a tuple of the addition along with a boolean indicating
>   whether an arithmetic overflow would occur. If an overflow would have
>   occurred then the wrapped value is returned.

Example:

```
use std::i64;

assert_eq!(5i64.overflowing_add(2), (7, false));
assert_eq!(i64::MAX.overflowing_add(1), (i64::MIN, true));
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5a61fb9ffee2900d5b5c11d598088b91&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 5):

Rust has integer arithmetic intrinsics such as [`add_with_overflow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.add_with_overflow.html).

```
pub unsafe extern "rust-intrinsic" fn add_with_overflow<T>(
    x: T, 
    y: T
) -> (T, bool)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why it's `unsafe`?

Comment: @delnan, all compiler intrinsincs are `unsafe` by default (they're an implementation detail that just gets imported via FFI with a custom ABI, and all FFI functions get marked `unsafe`, there is some thoughts to make this controllable/have safe intrinsics not-`unsafe`, but this is low priority).